# JPA spring @Transaction autocommit

Tags: java, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring-data-jpa with oracle.  I am unable to get @Transactional to rollback by default for runtime exception.

Here are snippets:

```
<persistence-unit name="dev2db" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="loginid" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="mypass" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

transactional method uses import javax.transaction.Transactional;

```
@Transactional
    public void uploadPanelAndAPK(String pz, byte[] file, String apk, byte[] fileApk, byte[] icon) {
        uploadPanel(pz, file);
        uploadApk(apk, fileApk, icon);

    }
```

if uploadApk fails uploadPanel is not doing rollback.

beans context.xml snippet:

```
<context:annotation-config />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.myco.dao" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" 
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
          p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>


    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          p:persistenceUnitName="dev2db">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="panelbo" class="com.myco.bo.PanelServiceSpringData"/>
```

Regards,

Miten.

Comment: Maybe something like this: `@Transactional(rollbackFor=RuntimeException.class, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`javax.transaction.Transactional` isn't (yet) supported. Use either `javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute` or `org.springframewor.transaction.annotation.Transactional`.